# DITA-OT 4.0.1 [DOTA015F][FATAL] Internal property preprocess.copy-html.skip may not be set directly. Use property build-step.copy-html instead

Tags: ms-word, docx, dita, dita-ot

jdk-17.0.3.1,
DITA-OT v.4.0.1, com.elovirta.ooxml  DITA to Word plug-in

Error while converting to DOCX:
`dita --input=phase.ditamap --format=docx`

```
[DOTA015F][FATAL] Internal property preprocess.copy-html.skip may not be set directly. Use property build-step.copy-html instead.
```

Please explain how to fix.
DITA-OT v.3.7.4 does not have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The Word to DITA plugin does not seem to be compatible with DITA OT 4.0 and newer, I added an internal issue for this on the project GitHub issues list and gave there a hint about how the build file can be modified to make things work again:

https://github.com/jelovirt/com.elovirta.ooxml/issues/101

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was helpful. Tell me please the therecom.antennahouse.wml is also not supported v.4, this trick does not work (use property build-step.chunk instead preprocess.chunk.skip).

Comment: I am not familiar with how the "com.antennahouse.wml" plugin works, it has a GitHub project from what I remember, maybe you can add an issue and ask them to try and support DITA OT 4.0. From what I know the Antenna House developers reply quickly and are helpful.